# Google direction API not returning traffic parameter

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I need the distance between two places and also estimated traveling time between them using google direction API.
I am using the documentation of google API.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

I am using below code.

```
 //Source address
    $a = 'Los Angeles International Airport, 1 World Way, Los Angeles, CA 90045, United States'; 
   //Destination address
    $b = 'Beverly Wilshire, Beverly Hills (A Four Seasons Hotel), 9500 Wilshire Boulevard, Beverly Hills, CA 90212, United
States';
//Pass source and destination address in google map API
    $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=' .urlencode($a) . '&destination=' .urlencode($b) . '&travelMode=google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING&drivingOptions=departureTime:1451302219|trafficModel:google.maps.TrafficModel.BEST_GUESS&key=AIzaSyC7h7m5bRs-BZwk0XTXEQTB74dZujeLzZs';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($xml);echo "<br/>";
```

I am not recieving the **duration_in_traffic** data in response(**$xml**).

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the `departure_time` parameter in the request. I modified your request like what is shown below and manage to get the `duration_in_traffic` in the response

Request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=place_id:ChIJtU-yE9KwwoAR8a2LaVd7qHc&destination=place_id:ChIJz-22Hfm7woARmoLOmvYW4J0&departure_time=1451302219&travelMode=google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING&drivingOptions=trafficModel:google.maps.TrafficModel.BEST_GUESS&key=API_KEY
```

Response(`duration_in_traffic portion):

```
<duration_in_traffic>
<value>1459</value>
<text>24 mins</text>
</duration_in_traffic>
```

Comment: Is there any way to get duration_in_traffic for BEST_GUESS, PESSIMISTIC and OPTIMISTIC in a single response at same call?

Answer (score 0):

For get the duration_in_traffic from google api you need to specify departure_time with the traffic mode.

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='.urlencode($a).'&destination='.urlencode($a).'&sensor=false&departure_time=1479142020&mode=driving&traffic_model=pessimistic&key='.API_KEY;
```